# C# Dynamic DataGridViewCell Click Event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have one DGV to be clicked and another ones to be created in accordance with this click type and to be displayed in screen for a special job purpose. During creation process of other DGV's some cells (some row-column logic) will be clicked automaticaly with program code. Code below performs AUTO CLICK code part of this action. But I believe there must be a another method (as in Button PerformClick Event Fire) to achive this click action:

```
            DataGridViewCell dc;
            dc = MyDataGridView[0, 0];
            Rectangle rect = this.MyDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 0, true);
            MouseButtons b = new MouseButtons();
            MouseEventArgs mev = new MouseEventArgs(b, 1, rect.X, rect.Y, 1);
            DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e = new DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(0, 0, rect.X + 2, rect.Y + 2, mev);
            MyDataGridView_CellMouseClick(dgvEntegCompany, e);
```

Comment: What is your question? A `DataGridView` already has a `CellMouseClick` event.

Comment: Why you want to explicitly execute the event handler ?

Comment: please think of "Button PerformClick" event when you need it dynamically, this time I need to click any required cell (col, row) of DataGridView. Code above solves my problem although  but I think there must be a SendMessage script for this...

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by… _”please think of "Button PerformClick" event when you need it dynamically,”_  ?… In addition, your comment… _”Code above solves my problem although but I think there must be a SendMessage script for this”_  ?… What "problem" does the code solve? The posted code looks unnecessary. Again what “problem” are you having and “how” is the posted code solving this problem or not solving it. I have already asked… what is your question.

Comment: thanks, I have an edit...

Comment: I mean no disrespect, however, are you intentionally dancing around a question. With each edit, we get a little more info about “what” you want to do, but still the problem is unknown and no question is asked. Please edit your statement to include a problem statement and what you have tried to solve the problem. I will refrain from any more fruitless back and forth and assume I am missing something. Good Luck.

Comment: **What I need is**: Fire Event Code for _DataGridView Cell Click At Any Column - Row_. Hope this is clear...

Comment: @biryaz Your edit is even more confusing. The answer to "Fire Event Code for DataGridView Cell Click At Any Column - Row" is a `CellClick` event, like you can see in my answer. I agree the code you provided is very confusing. At least you should comment every line to explain what are you trying to achieve. Perhaps we're missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even these two lines of code would perform the required action:

```
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(ColIdx, RowIdx);
MyDataGridvView_CellClick(myDGV, e);
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear. Are you just looking for a `CellClick` event?

EDIT: So do you need to execute the *content* of your CellClick? CellClick is an event, so it's triggered at the occurence of cell-click event. It can *contain* a call to a method, that you can also call independently, "dynamically", if you will.

```
    // CellClick event
    private void dgItems_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MyMessage(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
    }

    // A user method
    private void MyMessage(Int32 irow, Int32 icol)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("A cell [" + irow  + ", " + icol  + "] was clicked!");
    }

    // invoking from a button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyMessage(this.dgItems.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex, this.dgItems.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex );
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

There's no such thing as AUTOCLICK.

- If you want to execute a code inside the would-be-event, see code above
- If you want to perform visual changes, such as select a cell, just do it. Note, that this action is dependant on the setting of `SelectionMode`, it behaves way different for `Cell` and `FullRowSelect`, for instance. It's gonna be something like this:

```
    this.DataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    this.DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Selected = True;
```

- If you're looking for a way to invoke an action (aka computer AI player), you're most likely have to study multi-threading, i.e. `BackgroundWorker` and create a separate thread for controlling a game/simulation/etc. Then the question would be still light-years off

Remark: You have to do much better job expressing your questions, meaning putting much more effort into composing it. You're just wasting community time this way.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you mean to run the same method from a `CellClick` event and a `Button`, see a simple way in my edit. Otherwise please explain more clearly, what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that is what you mean by…

> *”Fire Event Code for DataGridView Cell Click At Any Column – Row”*

… Is that you want to subscribe to the grids event that will fire when any cell in the grid is “clicked” on by the user.

If this is the case… then, subscribe to the grids `CellClick` or `CellMouseClick` events.

If you want to subscribe to the grids `CellMouseClick` event, then the code for that can be done in the designer or you can add the code in the forms constructor after the `InitializeComponent();` method is called and it will look something like…

```
dataGridView1.CellMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellMouseClick);
```

Then you need to create the event handler method… `dataGridView1_CellMouseClick.` In this event you can check the `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` object to see which cell was clicked. The object has a property for the row index and column index of the clicked-on cell. Below is an example.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  // This event will fire whenever a user clicks on a cell
  // we can get the row and column index of the "clicked" cell
  MessageBox.Show("Cell at Row: " + e.RowIndex + " Col: " + e.ColumnIndex + "  was clicked");
}
```

This event will fire each time the user clicks on a cell in the grid.

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish with the current code.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realise the OP might not know how to subscribe to an event.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 ... I am still not sure if this is what the OP is asking. Like you commented, your answer is also correct.

Comment: I am very embarressed :), Forget **the grid is “clicked” on by the user.** , instead of user, code itself will create a grid and click a cell (detected by program code). As if you play chess against computer after your move machine will decide which figure will be moved and where to be moved...

Comment: I do not know what to say about your last comment that is not counterproductive. Your comment makes it sound like the computer has a mind of its own… _”As if you play chess against computer after your move machine will decide which figure will be moved and where to be moved.”_ …?  Machines are dumb and do NOT … _”decide which figure will be moved and where to be moved”_ … your code decides this.

Comment: I am sorry but I am done with this back and forth commenting that is getting absolutely nowhere. Maybe, edit your question with your last comment so others may be able to help. I am obviously out of ideas in relation to your whimsical question. Good Luck.

Comment: all the best @JohnG, thanks for so much efforts of yours...